# RFI: Moving from SQL Replication to MS Sync

Tags: replication, synchronization, microsoft-sync-framework, merge-replication

We are looking at replacing SQL Replication with another technology, possible MS SYNC.  We are synchronizing the data and schema for a large SAAS application between multiple data centers and require high availability, reliability and performance.

Questions:

1. Has anyone had experience moving from SQL replication to SYNC, if so what was your experience?
2. What are the performance and scalability considerations / constraints with SYNC?
3. Would you reccommend MS Sync for this scenario?

This is posted here, rather than the server site as the coding, testing and performance manipulation will most likely be experienced by developers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i have worked with both technologies and here's a a couple of things to consider:

1. Sync Framework dont synchronize schema changes
2. Sync Framework dont do partition realignment
3. Sync Framework is an SDK, so you build on top of it not unlike SQL replication which OOTB is a no-coding required implementation.
4. The newer Sync Framework database providers has no tooling support (read: no Visual Studio wizard or template), so you code from scratch.
5. Since Sync Framework is an SDK, you have address the HA, reliability and performance yourself (ie, load balanced WCF based sync services, sync retry, conflict handling, etc...)

having said above, Sync Framework on the other hand offers you more extensibility since its an SDK. The sync application is just another database application connecting to your databases, so the same application optimisations for database applications apply (good db design, indexing, frequent syncs, less dataset, etc...)

here's a link that compares [Sync Framework with Merge Replication](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2009/11/09/merge-replication-vs-sync-services-for-compact.aspx)

if you're databases are hosted in Sql Azure or on-premise, you might want to take a look at [Sql Azure Data Sync Service](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/sql-azure-data-sync-overview.aspx) as well.